# Semi-transparent colors in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, colors

Normally there are 16 colors in Terminal Emulators which can be defined by the user. Some Terminal Emulators allow 256 colors to be customized.

However, is it possible to make any of these colors semi-transparent? The purpose is to see if we can change the `Vim`s errors and warning colors in a slightly more user friendly way with transparency. I was thinking of over-riding some of the colors in 16-32 range.

PS: I am using Arch Linux here with Terminix TE. If this is OS, TE dependent, any solution would also work. I can consider switching, Just kidding :).

Comment: Assuming you are using Linux, take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent

Comment: What operating system? What terminal program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, do I understand correctly that you'd like an app (e.g. `vim`) to be able to use colors such as e.g. solid green, solid blue, semi-transparent red etc.?

I haven't heard of such feature in any of the emulators. Terminix, in particular, uses the VTE widget which does not support this.

The exact value of the 256-color palette can be modified using the OSC 4 escape sequence in some of the terminal emulators, yet the new value is always an RGB, not RGBA which you'd need.

Similarly, several terminal emulators support direct RGB colors, but I haven't found any sign of RGBA anywhere.

All the standard 8/16, extended 256, or direct RGB 16 million colors are solid colors. In addition to these there's the "default" color for foreground and background, here the background can have an image or transparency depending on the emulator.

PS. I don't get why you think that a semi-transparent error message would be user friendly. A screenshot mockup could probably help us imagine why you'd like to have this feature.

Comment: I was just curious. I just thought some forms of highlighting would be neat in case it is possible. Perhaps you are right about semi-transparent error message not being user friendly. Its best to keep TE, TE sometimes.